# Disable Out Of Browser mode in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to remove the option to install the application (i.e. out of browser mode) from my Silverlight app, but can't seem to find any examples on how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a checkbox on the Silverlight tab for the project properties.

Comment: I didn't even think to look in project properties.  Thanks!